# Ionic reorder list item is not working in iOS 12

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ios12

We are using Ionic V1 directive ion-reorder for drag and drop list item with angular v1.4 and it is not working in iOS 12. The same is working in the iOS 11 and below.

Will ion-reorder-button in [IonicListDelegate](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionList/) work in iOS 12?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic framework v1 is no longer supported in iOS 12, in order to make iOS applications with Ionic you have to learn angular 2+ and use newer versions of Ionic.